# Non-Transversal Fault Tolerant Gate

Tags: quantum-computing, fault-tolerance

I have always heard that transversality is a sufficient, not a necessary condition for fault-tolerance in quantum computation. However, I have never seen any examples of non-transversal fault tolerant gates. Does anyone know of any?

Comment: There are lots of examples of non-transversal fault-tolerant gates. None of them are simple, unfortunately. To get an idea of what they look like, and find some references, you could look at sections 4.5 and 4.6 of [Dan Gottesman's survey article,](http://arxiv.org/abs/0904.2557).